# File param is a string, instead of object

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
Rails 5.1
```

In my form, I have:

```
.container
  h4
    = t('fw_exports.choose_file_to_upload')
  //= form_tag url: process_imported_spreadsheet_path, html: { multipart: true }
  = form_tag({controller: :fw_exports, action: :process_imported_spreadsheet}, multipart: true)
    .form-group
      = file_field_tag :import_file
    .form_group
      = text_field_tag :screen_name_addition, nil, placeholder: "Screen Name To Add"
    = button_tag(type: 'submit', class: "btn btn-primary") do
      i.icon-ok.icon-white
      = t('fw_exports.import')
```

but when I submit the form, I get these params:

```
Parameters: 
  {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"...", 
  "import_file"=>"test.csv", 
  "screen_name_addition"=>"testname", 
  "button"=>""}
```

The import_file field is a string, instead of an object. I believe I'm using the proper syntax (I also tried the line I commented out).

Here's the HTML:

```
<form html="{:multipart=>true}" action="/process_imported_spreadsheet" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">
  <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓">
  <input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value=".....">
  <input type="file" name="import_file" id="import_file">
  <button name="button" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="icon-ok icon-white"></i>Import</button>
</form>
```

Any advice?

Comment: Hmm, I missed that you where using `multipart: true`. However when I set this up on Rails 5 I get a `ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile` as expected.

Comment: Which is why I am puzzled

Comment: Does the generated HTML have `enctype="multipart/form-data"`?

Comment: You can try calling it as `form_tag process_imported_spreadsheet_path, html: { multipart: true }`

Comment: I posted the html. I've already tried what you're suggesting (see my question, the commented out line.

Comment: It actually slightly different as the url is an ordinal argument instead of a option. Try it.

Comment: I did try it with and without the url. Same result.

Comment: What version of Rails are you using? In Rails 5.0 `form_tag('/foo', multipart: true)` does work. Using the `html` option does not as it has no special meaning and just gets slurped and turned into a an attribute.

Comment: I am using Rails 5.1. I will try it without using html

Comment: In Rails 5.1 I would use [form_with](https://m.patrikonrails.com/rails-5-1s-form-with-vs-old-form-helpers-3a5f72a8c78a) instead. The `html` option is just for `form_for` which has a different signature which is why `form_with` replaces both.

Comment: This seems to work: = form_tag(process_imported_spreadsheet_path, multipart: true) I am now getting <ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:... I will also try form_with, I would like to stick with Rails 5.1 syntax

Answer (score 0):

Use `form_with` instead of `form_tag` in Rails 5.1+

```
= form_with url: process_imported_spreadsheet_path, multipart: true do |form|
  = form.import_file
```

This replaces `form_tag` and `form_for` with a single method. Among other things this fixes your issue which is cause by the different signatures for `form_for` and `form_tag`.

`form_for` uses the `html` option. `form_tag` does not.

```
= form_tag 'foo', html: { multipart: true } do
```

Will render:

```
<form html="{:multipart=&gt;true}" action="/foo" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">
```

As any options without special significance are just added as attributes. The wierd `{:multipart=&gt;true}` is from `.to_s` being called implicitly on the hash.

These do work:

```
= form_tag '/foo', multipart: true } do
= form_tag {controller: :foo, action: :index }, multipart: true  do

# renders
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/foo" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">
```